# segmentation fault with openmp legacy code

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am trying to applying openmp to legacy fortran code and I tried to do as following but I encounter a runtime error while running the code.

```
Line 89 of expect.f is the line: rv_avg(m) = rv_avg(m) + psi(k,m)*psi(k,m)*rosc(k)

forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
main               0000000000411CE9  expect_                    89  expect.f
libiomp5.so        00002B13E9690FE3  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Command exited with non-zero status 174
```

I have make stack large enough with ulimit and export KMP_STACKSIZE. I am wondering what went wrong and any suggestions about how to optimizing the legacy code. Thanks a lot!

```
login1$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 514847
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 150
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 8388608
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

```
!$OMP PARALLEL shared(ng,nstates,natoms,psi,rosc,grt,frt)
!$OMP DO private(k,m)&
!$OMP& reduction(+:rv_avg,b_avg)
      do k = 1, ng
         do m = 0, nstates - 1
            rv_avg(m) = rv_avg(m) + psi(k,m)*psi(k,m)*rosc(k)
            b_avg(m) = b_avg(m) + psi(k,m)*psi(k,m)/(mu*rosc(k)**2)
         enddo
      enddo
!$OMP ENDDO 

!$OMP DO private(k,m,j)&
!$OMP& reduction(+:grt_avg)     
      do k = 1,ng
         do m = 0, nstates -1
            do j = 1, 3
               grt_avg(m,j) = grt_avg(m,j) + psi(k,m)*psi(k,m)*grt(k,j)
            enddo
         enddo
      enddo    
!$OMP ENDDO

!$OMP DO private(k,m,j,l)&
!$OMP reduction(+:frt_avg)
      do k = 1,ng  
         do m = 0, nstates -1
            do j = 1,3
               do l = 1, natoms
                  frt_avg(m,l,j) = frt_avg(m,l,j)   &
                       + psi(k,m)*psi(k,m)*frt(k,l,j)
                enddo
             enddo
         enddo
      enddo
!$OMP DO private(k,m,j,l,mp)&
!$OMP reduction(+:d_coup)      
      do k = 1,ng
         do m =0 , nstates - 1
            do j = 1,natoms
               do l = 1, natoms
                  do mp = 0, nstates - 1
                     d_coup(m,mp,l,j) = d_coup(m,mp,l,j)   &
                          + psi(k,m)*psi(k,mp)*frt(k,l,j)
                  enddo
               enddo
            enddo
         enddo
      enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm immediately suspicious of these lines

```
     do m = 0, nstates - 1
        rv_avg(m) = rv_avg(m) + psi(k,m)*psi(k,m)*rosc(k)
```

because they suggest that the code reads from and writes to element `0` of array `rv_avg`.  Since, by default, Fortran array indexing is 1-based, such accesses may give rise to a segmentation fault.

It is possible that the declaration of `rv_avg` sets an index lower bound of `0` or less, perhaps `rv_avg(0:99)`.

Comment: thanks for your comment. It is not strictly fortran 77 with array index starts from 0 in declaration like rv_avg(0:maxsts) while has many 77 features as far as I can tell. Since the corresponding serial code works fine,so that is not the reason about the segmentation fault I have. I am more interested in what openmp practices I did caused the runtime error or what are the suggested practices i should adopt.

Comment: @user1509376 When there is a memory violation, a program sometimes still finishes without runtime errors.  Did you try including bound/initialization checks or, even better, can you post the declaration statement of the variables in that line?

Comment: A serial program with an unknown incorrect array access statement may run just fine on one thread and then fail miserably when parallelised.  OpenMP has a big impact on the layout of variables in memory.  Since the run time error seems to occur on a line where array elements are read and written, rather than allocated, you should do as @XiaoleiZhu suggests and use your compiler to check that there are no out-of-bounds array accesses.

Comment: It is something like:                                             double precision  frt_avg(0:maxsts,maxatoms,3),rv_avg(0:maxsts)

Comment: "Use your compiler to check that there are no out-of-bounds array accesses.", really.

Comment: what is not F77 is the use of do ... enddo , the comment !, the small letters... But declaring an array (0:99) is F77 !

Comment: @user1509376, how big do you set the worker threads stack with `KMP_STACKSIZE` and what are the values of `maxsts` and `maxatoms`? That `frt_avg` could possibly be quite big given large number of atoms and states.

Comment: @FrancoisJacq: thanks for the (re-)education.  My answer is now less misleading.